# flutter) The status of the icon can't be changed immediately (Edit)

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I made it possible to toggle the heart icon in the post like Instagram.
And I implemented it so that user information is uploaded to the firestore when I toggle the icon.
There is no problem with the 'Like' and 'Unlike' function of 'Like Icon', but there is one other problem.
There is a problem that the color of the icon does not change immediately when toggling the icon in the post.  I can check that this icon has changed when I go to a different screen and come back in.

The following is the code for this icon. (I edited this code)

```
    class LikeToggleIcon extends StatefulWidget {
      final String postKey;
      final PostModel postModel;
    
      const LikeToggleIcon(
          {Key key,
          this.postKey,
          this.postModel,
          this.fromSearch,
          this.searchResults})
          : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      State<LikeToggleIcon> createState() => _LikeToggleIconState();
    }
    
    class _LikeToggleIconState extends State<LikeToggleIcon> {
      // bool _isLiked = false;
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        //get userModel
        UserModel userModel =
            Provider.of<UserModelState>(context, listen: false).userModel;
    
          return IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              // setState(() {
                postNetworkRepo.toggleLike(
                    widget.postModel.postKey, userModel.userKey);
              // });
            },
            icon: Icon(
              widget.postModel.numOfLikes.contains(userModel.userKey)
                  ? Icons.favorite_outlined
                  : Icons.favorite_border_outlined,
              size: 27,
              color: Colors.redAccent,
            ),
          );




    //toggle method
    class PostNetworkRepo with Transformers {
          Future<void> toggleLike(String postKey, String userKey) async {
            final DocumentReference postRef =
                Firestore.instance.collection(COLLECTION_POSTS).document(postKey);
            final DocumentSnapshot postSnapshot = await postRef.get();
        
            //check Post collection
            if (postSnapshot.exists) {
              //check already contain userKey 
              //if no contain upload userKey, else delete userKey (toggle Like/Unlike)
              if (postSnapshot.data[KEY_NUMOFLIKES].contains(userKey)) {
                postRef.updateData({
                  KEY_NUMOFLIKES: FieldValue.arrayRemove([userKey])
                });
              } else {
                postRef.updateData({
                  KEY_NUMOFLIKES: FieldValue.arrayUnion([userKey])
                });
              }
            }
          }
        }
        
        PostNetworkRepo postNetworkRepo = PostNetworkRepo();

//This is the part of detail post screen.
class DetailScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _DetailScreenState createState() => _DetailScreenState();
}

class _DetailScreenState extends State<DetailScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
//get userModel 
    UserModel userModel =
        Provider.of<UserModelState>(context, listen: false).userModel;

              return Scaffold(
                appBar: AppBar(
                  title: _postUser(),
                  actions: [
                     //toggle likeIcon
                     LikeToggleIcon(
                       postKey: widget.postKey,
                       postModel: widget.postModel,
                     ),
                  ],
            ),
```

I tried using `setState()` on the `IconButton()`, but the problem was not solved.

can I get help with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using `setState()` to change value of variable that's inside the **Widget** and NOT the **State** of that widget.

You need to have variables that changes the Widget inside the state for it to be updated. Keeping it inside Widget won't change the Icon, unless the whole widget is recreated (like when you change the screen).

(correct me if I'm wrong. Providing full code of the widget could be more useful)